# Intuition about a matrixs transpose and why the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading a book on linear algebra and specifically the chapter about inverse matrices and orthogonal matrices. The explanation of why the inverse of an orthogonal square matrix is its transpose, makes algebraic sense to me, but I am having a hard time understanding it beyond that.

I conceive of square matrices as a set of column vectors that tell you where the map of the unit vectors will end up
$$A=(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2\\a_3&b_3&c_3\end{pmatrix}$$
$\hat{e_x}$ will end up at $\vec{a}$ and so on.

An orthogonal matrix is isometric all lengths of vectors and the angels between the will remain the same for their maps. Since this can only be rotation or mirroring it makes sense to me that the matrix has an inverse and, as I stated in the beginning, the algebraic explanation why the transpose is the inverse is understandable. But what does it mean to map a vector with the transpose of a matrix compared to the original map?
What can you say about the transpose map of a general matrix geometrically?

For higher dimensions I view matrices as systems of equation. Does it make sense to interpret a meaning, other than the purely algebraic, of $A^t\vec{x}=y$ in relationship to $A\vec{x}=y$ for general matrices?

I can't find the intuition right now so my question is not as concrete as I would like, but hopefully someone will point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of *orthogonal matrix* ? Usually, the fact that $A^{-1} = A^T$ *is* precisely the definition.

Comment: Perhaps the dot product can help in understanding the transpose. Let $M$ be a matrix and $X,Y$ vectors. We have $$\langle X| M | Y\rangle = \langle Y| M^T | X\rangle \\
\langle M^TY, X\rangle = \langle Y , MX\rangle  
$$
So the dot product of $M^T Y$  with $X$ is the same as the dot product of $Y$ with $MX$. I believe this relationship can be used to define the transpose.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe My book defines orthogonal matrix as "A linear map from $R^n\ to\ R^n$ that is described by the matrix A is called an isometric map if it preserves the length of the vector $|A\vec{x}|=|\vec{x}|$ for all $\vec{x} \in R^n$. The corresponding matrix A is called an orthogonal matrix"

Comment: The preservation of lengths makes it preserve inner product, due to the [polarization identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity). So, if you have that for all $x,y$, $(x,y)=(Ax,Ay)=(A^*Ax,y)$, then $((A^*A-I)x,y)=0$. Putting $y=(A^*A-I)x$ we get that $\|(A^*A-I)x\|=0$ for all $x$. Then $(A^*A-I)x=0$ for all $x$. Therefore, $A^*A-I=0$. Here $A^*$ is the transpose, or the transpose conjugate if your scalars are the complex numbers.

Comment: @user3257842 Thank you. I don't know all the signs you use, but I think I get what you are trying to say and it gives me a few ideas.

Comment: If you have  a dot product (inner product) of two vectors, applying a matrix  (linear transformation) $M$ to one of them has the same effect on the result as would have applying the transpose transformation $M^T$ to the other.